# Rename an Image in MVC Core2 Controller - not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, file-rename

How do I rename an image in an MVC core 2 controller.?

The code below is not working and nothing is done:

```
string savelocation = path;
string fileExtention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);
//creating filename to avoid file name conflicts.
string NewName = id.ToString();// id is actually the Primary key
//saving file in savedImage folder.
var savePath = savelocation + NewName + fileExtention;

string result2 = "/uploads/" + user + "/" + Path.GetFileName(savePath);

var stream3 = new FileStream(NewName, FileMode.Create);
files[0].CopyTo(stream3);

stream3.Flush();
stream3.Dispose();
```

Comment: what does not working mean?

Comment: and what is `files`?

Comment: apologies I did not specify what files were, it was just the result of var files = request.form.files array object, I found the problem and will answer below, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i changed my code and here is the new working code

```
var stream3 = new FileStream(NewName, FileMode.Create);
```

was changed to

```
var stream3 = new FileStream( savePath, FileMode.Create);
```